# AS3 Call to possibly undefined method with a static type Class issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, oop, class

Receiving an error
Call to possibly undefined method getStartButton through a reference of static type class
This is also happening for getQuitButton

I'm still lost on how to utilize classes as I'm new to OOP. Can someone please help me to understand what I'm doing incorrectly?

Here the function in my main class:

```
function getStartMenu():void {
    var bFormat:TextFormat, bStart:Sprite, bQuit:Sprite;

    bStart = StartMenu.getStartButton();
    bQuit = StartMenu.getQuitButton();

    bStart.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, bStartPress);
    bQuit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, bQuitPress);
}
```

in my external class file StartMenu.as

```
package
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;

    public class StartMenu extends Sprite
    {

        public function StartMenu():void
        {

        }

        public function getStartButton():Sprite {
            var bFormat:TextFormat, bStart:Sprite, bStartText:TextField;
            bFormat = getFormat();
            bStart = getMenuButton(uint("0X00FF00"));
            bStart.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - bStart.width - 100;
            bStart.y = stage.stageHeight - bStart.height - 100;
            bStartText = getTextButton(bFormat, "Start");
            bStartText.defaultTextFormat = bFormat;
            return bStart;
        }

        public function getQuitButton():Sprite {
            var bFormat:TextFormat, bQuit:Sprite, bQuitText:TextField
            bFormat = getFormat();
            bQuit = getMenuButton(uint("0X0000FF"));
            bQuit.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 + 100;
            bQuit.y = stage.stageHeight - bQuit.height - 100;
            bQuitText = getTextButton(bFormat, "Quit");
            bQuitText.defaultTextFormat = bFormat;
            return bQuit;
        }


        public function getFormat():TextFormat {
            var bFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat()
            bFormat.font = "Arial";
            bFormat.bold = true;
            bFormat.color = 0x000000;
            bFormat.size = 28;
            bFormat.align = "center";
            return bFormat;
        }

        public function getMenuButton(bColor:uint):Sprite {
            var bButton:Sprite = new Sprite();
            bButton.graphics.beginFill(bColor, 1);
            bButton.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 50);
            bButton.graphics.endFill();
            bButton.buttonMode = true;
            bButton.mouseChildren = false;
            return bButton
        }

        public function getTextButton(bFormat:TextFormat, sText:String):TextField {
            var bText:TextField = new TextField()
            bText.defaultTextFormat = bFormat
            bText.text = sText;
            bText.x = -4;
            bText.y = 4;
            return bText;
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`StartMenu.getStartButton();` is how you would call a static method, since `getStartButton` isn't static you are getting this error.

You can turn `getStartButton` to be a static method by changing it to :

```
public static function getStartButton():Sprite
```

Or you can create an instance of the `StartMenu` class and call it's instance methods.

```
var startMenu:StartMenu = new StartMenu();
var bStart:Sprite = startMenu.getStartButton();
```

Comment: +1 what's the difference between setting the function as public static vs creating an instance of the class and then calling the function?

Comment: If a function is static you don't need to create an instance of that class to use it's methods, instead you just use the class name to call it as in `StartMenu.getStartButton`. Static methods are usually used with classes that don't hold internal state. For example the `Math` class in AS3 all its methods are static.

Comment: Are there any pros/cons to creating the instance first vs setting the function as public static? I suppose I don't see the advantage within my narrow scope of understanding of OOP

Comment: Not really but sometimes you have to create instances of classes to use them. For example you have to create sprites to be able to add them to the stage. `var sp:Sprite = new Sprite();` There is no other way to do this. But if you are making a class that is like the `Math` class in AS3 you can make all of its members static. Here is some more reading : http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/as3-101-quick-tip-%E2%80%93-when-to-use-static-properties-and-methods/ Not that I am not really a fan of global access and singletons. But it makes sense for stuff like the Math class

Comment: I'd like to add that from my external class, I had to remove the references of stage and adding the textfield object to their respective sprites via addChild(), and also setting the sprite objects to the stage from the main class. Now alls works.